# azure CLI 2.0 az webapp log tail cannot find the 'NAME' of my webapp

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-cli

When i was using the Azure CLI 1.0, i use the following command to log tail my webapp:

```
azure login 
azure site log tail MY_WEBAPP_NAME
```

Now after i have switched to Azure CLI 2.0, i cannot find the name of my webapp using the supposingly equivalent command az webapp log tail, when I type:

> azure login //then follow the login procedures

```
azure webapp log tail--name MY_WEBAPP_NAME
```

it returns:

> az webapp log tail: error: (--resource-group | --ids) are required

I cannot figure out how i could use the command successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`azure site log` It is a asm mode cmdlet. Azure Cli 2.0 only supports arm mode.

Modify your cmdlet like below:

```
az webapp log tail -g <rg name> -n <webapp name>
```

or

```
az webapp log tail --ids /subscriptions/3b4d41fa-e91d-****-****/resourceGroups/shuiapp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/shuiphp
```

[image]

Note: You could find rgname and webapp name and ids on new [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com).